# Badge count on Xamarin.iOS app icon incorrect after app re-install

Tags: push-notification, xamarin.ios

I have a badge on my Xamarin.iOS app that shows how many unread notifications there are. I'm using UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber to set the badge count when the app starts up and whenever the unread notifications count changes. If I delete the app when the badge is showing 2 unread notifications, and I re-install it, the app icon still shows the 2 unread notifications from the old install. What needs to be done so a new install accurately shows no unread notifications (and no badge showing)?

Answer (score 0):

You could define a property in the app by using **NSUserDefaults** . The property will been created when you first load the app and been moved when uninstall it  .

```
      var plist = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;

        if(plist.BoolForKey("IsNeedSetBadge"))
        {
            //set badge
        }
        else
        {
            //first load , set this value

            plist.SetBool(true, "IsNeedSetBadge");

        }
```

Comment: The problem is, the badge icon is showing unread notifications after a delete/re-install, **before** the app has been run for the first time after the re-install. The app would have to run to execute the code you are suggesting.

Comment: If so you could use keychain . Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336016/cant-access-saved-in-a-xamarin-ios-keychain-value .